# GSA: ignoring "num" parameter

Tags: google-search-appliance

For some reason my customers GSA always returns 10 results no matter what we send with the "num" parameter:
http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1076882

Is there a global configuration that we are missing that overrides what is sent as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In GSA, there isn't a globally configuration which can override the num-parameter. If you use the num-parameter in the search query, it should return that number of results you assign in the parameter (with a maximum of 1000). So, you are sure that there are more than 10 results for the query you used?

The other thing I can think of, is that a proxy handles the search requests and responses. The parameters can then be controlled by this proxy, so whatever parameter you add in the URL is ignored since the proxy / the backend handles these.

Comment: it seems, filter=1 screws up our whole search results. I don't get a total number of results, just max. 10 results and <M> is also the number of results returned. We now set it to filter=0 again and need to find a way to filter duplicates.